# Best way to load tabbed content

Tags: ajax, user-interface, tabs

I'm working on changing member profile UI on one site. Project page: http://design.vitalbmx.com/user_menu/member_profile2.html

**Goals:**

**Usability:** page load time must be optimized, especially images in the active tab
**SEO:** pagination links within tabs must be crawlable

**Assumptions:**

- Most users will go to "All" tab by default
- Most users will rarely click other tabs except "All"
- Most users will not send links to paginated tabs, only to 1st page of any given tab

**Implementation scenarios:**

1. Content of all tabs is loaded at once on the same page. Pagination via Ajax (with URL's to existing pages for crawlers). Possible issues - lag for loading images for tabs other than first tab if it's set in page URL (e.g. #videos)
2. Content of first tab ("All") to load first. Load content of other tabs only when they are clicked. Issues - extra HTTP calls and also lag for loading images for tabs other than first tab
3. Content of all tabs is loaded on the same page BUT image sources are replaced with a generic image for tabs other than current tab before images begin loading. When another tab is clicked (or after current tab images are loaded) image sources are reverted to original and begin loading (somewhat like Mashable.com but without the annoying fade-in effect)
4. Ajax-less - dedicated page for each tab. Makes more sense for SEO than for usability. Easy to copy-paste-send URL's with pagination.

Which one would be the best? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with no. 4, because that one uses less load from server and client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up doing it the #2. Initial tab is loaded server side, any other tab loads with Ajax. Works pretty well and is fast. At the same time, each tab has a permanent URL too.